# Restricting user so that the logged-in user cannot open sign_in and sign_up page indirectly by writting exact URL into the browsers search bar?

Tags: php

I want to restrict logged in users so that they cannot open sign_in and sign_up page indirectly by entering exact url into the browsers search bar. I want if they try to access the restricted page they should be redirected to 404.php. I have also used this but it isn't working

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($obj->curPageName() == "sign_in.php")) { ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                location = "404.php";
            </script>           
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What are you doing to protect protected pages from *not* logged-in users? You just need to do the reverse here. And don't redirect by Javascript, that's no protection. Redirect via an HTTP `Location` header!

Comment: <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) {  ?><li><a href="sign_in.php"> Sign In</a></li><?php } ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, 404 is for page not found, and not to stop the users to access pages which requires credentials, instead, start a session at the top of the page using `session_start()` and set a session var with a value false..

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = false;
```

When the user logs in, change the bool value to true

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
```

Now on the pages, which requires the credentials to access.. use a condition with `header()` to redirect the user if he is not logged in

```
if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']) && $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] == false) {
   header('Location: login.php');
   exit;
}
```

Things to look for : You are using JS to redirect which is extremely dirty coding, what if user disables JavaScript, redirection will fail..

Add : If you want to set a custom error, you can save it in a session, throw the error if the user accesses the page directly which requires login, and you can `unset` the `var` after you throw him an error, like the page you are trying to access requires you to log in

Comment: Again, I am explaining a story. Suppose, the user have logged in and he writes this into the browsers search bar: www.example.com/sign_in.php. I want the user when he writes this URL and press enter he should be redirected to my customized 404.php page template

Comment: @aleeza Again, answer is above, read it properly, and again, 404 is page not found

Comment: Redirecting to a 404 page when a page actually exists but you want to make it unaccessible is not user friendly at all and really not recommended. Just redirect to the page he should be after he logs in normally...